Alternate word for neighborhood
In engineering writing, I require a noun to signify a simple, contiguous region in the Argand or complex plane.  By this I mean a region bounded by an O-shaped or D-shaped curve, say, but not by an 8-shaped, P-shaped or OO-shaped curve, nor by an inner curve that cuts out a hole.
Moreover, ideally, I would like to be able to apply the adjectives open and closed alternately to exclude or include the region's boundary.  That is, if the noun were "frotz," then I would like to be able to speak alternately of an "open frotz" and a "closed frotz."  However, if this is not possible, then I prefer the open frotz.
Are there any ordinary English nouns like neighborhood or locale I can use without contradicting established topological or measure-theoretic usage?
(For information, no one is going to try Lebesgue integration or anything like it in my region, no one is going to ask questions about isomorphisms or non-Euclidean metrics, and my audience has hardly heard names like Banach or Tarski: this is engineering, not logic.  Therefore, I am not too particular about fine points of usage.  I merely need a plain, dignified English noun unlikely to provoke pointless confusion over semantics.)

Would the term "domain" be sufficient? I'm not the biggest fan of the term since it used in only a billion different ways in mathematics, but it's something.

I'll be honest, while I find this question kind of intriguing, I don't think that it is a very good fit for Math SE---it is too opinion based, and there is not really an authoritative, objectively right, answer.  For example, I think that "domain" is a bad, as it already means an open connected subset of the complex plane.  I am also somewhat confused, because you say that you want to describe O- and D-shaped regions (which have holes in them), but then you say that you want to describe regions without holes.  These seem contradictory to me.

However, if you want to describe connected regions without holes, it seems like you are interested in simply connected sets.  But you haven't really given a good enough description of what you are after to be sure... Since you describe wanting a word for certain types of "simple, contiguous regions", why not just explicitly describe what you are looking for, call such a thing a "good region" or an "acceptable region" or an "interesting region" or whatever (i.e. add an adjective to "region") and get on with your life?

Sounds like you just want to talk about subsets $A,B\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $A$ is homeomorphic to the open unit disk, and $B$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit disk. So, if you’re just writing a ‘localized’ document, then just make up your own terminology, such as open/closed basic region or open/closed simple region or open/closed elementary region.

@PrincessEev: the article you link is both interesting and readable. Meanwhile, unfortunately, my draft already uses the term "domain" in one of the billion ways you have mentioned; so I'd have to change that term, too, if it came to it.

@peek-a-boo: indeed, that is just what I want to talk about.

And in fact the Riemann mapping theorem tells us that every non-empty, proper, simply-connected open subset of the plane is biholomorphic, hence homeomorphic to the open unit disk, so the use of adjective simple is a-posteriori justifiable.

@XanderHenderson: I have edited the question to clarify the O and D shapes and, I hope, to make it a little less opinion-based.

If you really only want things where the boundary is either an O or a D, then there's no pre-existing term, so you can just give a definition at the beginning, and call them "open (resp. closed) OD regions". Like Xander implies, the word "region" isn't very rigidly defined, so you can pick it up and have it do what you want it to do.

@JonathanZ: your comment is a true mathematician's comment and is appreciated in this sense. Engineers tend to stumble over mathematicians' terminology when the mathematician seeks generalization while the engineer only wishes to visualize a specific scenario to set up a particular computation. No, I don't especially only want things where the boundary is either an O or a D, but I also don't want to spend several pages expanding my definition to its logically permissible extent—and anyway I would get it wrong if I tried. The O and D shapes happen to suffice for my purpose; that's all.

Yeah, it's true even for mathématiciens: if you've got some end goal, but need some intermediary object, then pick your intermediary object the simplest and most convenient way possible. So I say, if O and D suffice, then make that your definition, and get to the other stuff a quickly as possible. (You can always add a comment that your claims are true of a wider class of regions, but O and D are all you need here.)

If it's allowed to be spiky and rough and non-convex, but not self-intersecting, then it sounds like (the interior of) a Jordan curve. But if you don't even want to think about the technicalities, there's nothing stopping you calling this a "blob" or something, and defining that term in whatever way is appropriate for your audience.

While teaching, whenever I want to leave the level of technical detail more than a bit fuzzy, I simply draw a blob on the chalkboard, and refer to it as an amoeba (my students quickly learn my idiosyncratic lingo, using it in vector calculus as well as group theory). Mind you, my amoebas can have holes and whatnot. It sounds like you may be aiming at one of starlike/convex/simplyconnected open/closed sets, but I'm not sure. Do you want to see pictures clariifying their differences?

@JyrkiLahtonen: of course, I would study your pictures with interest if you posted them, but your verbal description suffices, I think.

Perhaps the terminology you want is a Jordan domain.
A common feature of an "$O$-shaped or $D$-shaped curve" is that they are both homeomorphic to the unit circle $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$.
In general a subset $C$ of the plane homeomorphic to $S^1$ is called a Jordan curve. The Jordan curve theorem says that $C$ separates the plane into two (connected) components: a bounded component called the "inside" of $C$; and an unbounded component called the "outside" of $C$. The union of $C$ and its inside is called a Jordan domain.
The terminology is, perhaps, a bit ambiguous in that sometimes only the inside is called a Jordan domain. So you could easily take advantage of that ambiguity, and adapt the terminology, to refer to a "closed Jordan domain" or an "open Jordan domain".

There is no standard expression for such a thing. It is moreover not really clear what you mean by an "O-shaped or D-shaped curve, say, but not by an 8-shaped, P-shaped or OO-shaped curve".
However, "region" is definitely used to denote a non-empty connected open set in the plane. So perhaps you mean a convex region. This excludes boundaries which are "8-shaped, P-shaped or OO-shaped" and "holes inside the region".

I actually had not been thinking of convexity, but now that you mention it, convexity would simplify my application. I like it, especially if the convex region is open, which implies that it necessarily has an interior, since it consists of nothing but an interior.
